# Get CellTemplate binding from GridViewColumn

Tags: c#, wpf, gridviewcolumn, celltemplate

So, I have this ListView that needs to use some custom compare functions depending on what is bound.
Right now the only solution I have found so far is to have a custom property to declare (`SortablePropertyName`) what has been used as binding source, when using  CellTemplates for binding more complex objects, such as object with both icon and text.

```
...
<ui:MyListView Grid.Row="1" ItemsSource="{Binding SubComponents}" SelectionChanged="SubComponentSelectionChanged" SelectionMode="Extended" VirtualizingStackPanel.IsVirtualizing ="False" Margin="2" DefaultSortingColumnHeader="Label" Grid.ColumnSpan="2">
  <ui:MyListView.View>
     <GridView>
         <ui:MyGridViewColumn Header="Solution" Width="200" SortBy="Context" SortablePropertyName="SolutionVisualizationViewModel">
           <GridViewColumn.CellTemplate>
               <DataTemplate>
                  <bcp:MyObjectVisualizationView DataContext="{Binding SolutionVisualizationViewModel}"/>
               </DataTemplate>
           </GridViewColumn.CellTemplate>
       </ui:MyGridViewColumn>
...
```

Because later on when dealing with sorting I need information of what property of the ViewModel that has been used for current column.

```
foreach (MyGridViewColumn column in columns)
{
    //Sort by context
    if (column.SortBy == MyListViewSorting.SortOption.Context)
       {   
        if (column.SortDirectionType == MyListViewSorting.SortDirectionType.Ascending)
           {             
               listViewCollection.CustomSort = new ContextComparer(column.SortablePropertyName);
            }
...
```

I can by adding `DependencyObject data = column.CellTemplate.LoadContent() as DependencyObject;` get hold of what view has been used, but still not what I want.

Is there away to find out this binding 'DataContext="{Binding VisualizationViewModel}' associated with a column without having to use a property?
Is there any "links" to be found between bindings and a GridViewColumn to hopefully solve this problem?

Comment: A template is a template. The `MyObjectVisualizationView` in the template is *eventually* instantiated. Why and where are you trying to iterate through the columns?

Comment: Its part of when sorting need to be updated, as multiple of them are set up for specific sorting depending on their induvial type of contents.

Comment: Why can't you use the `SortablePropertyName` that you seem to have there?

Comment: I can and I am. How ever, I wonder if there is a way to void this property. If there is a way to find what has been bound by template from the GridColumn at runtime.

Answer (score 0):

> Is there away to find out this binding 'DataContext="{Binding VisualizationViewModel}' associated with a column without having to use a property?

You could realize the template using the `LoadContent()` method and check the `DataContext` property of the root element in it.

Or, assuming that the template has already been applied, you could use `GetCellContent` method to get a reference to the root element.

You may also override the `GenerateElement` method.

But using a property is probably easier.

A template is just a template and there is no element instantiated, binding applied och source value being resolved until it's actually applied. The column doesn't care/know what's in its `CellTemplate`. It just realizes the template.